# IndexOutOfRangeException with Merge sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, sorting, mergesort

This is how my class is designed:

```
    class MergeSort
    {
        int[] mArray;
        public MergeSort(int[] A)
        {
            mArray = A;
        }
        void Merge(int[] A,int p ,int q, int r)
        {
            int n1 = q - p + r;
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int n2 = r - q;
            int[] left = new int[n1+1];
            int[] right = new int[n2+1];
            for ( i = 0; i < n1; i++)
                left[i] = A[p + i - 1];
            for ( i = 0; i < n2; i++)
                right[i] = A[q + i];
            left[n1] = Int32.MaxValue;
            right[n2] = Int32.MaxValue;
            i = j = 0;
            for (int k = p; k < r; k++)
            {
                if (left[i] <= right[j])
                {
                    A[k] = left[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    A[k] = right[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }

        }
        public void Merge_Sort(int[] A, int p, int r)
        {
            int q = 0;
            mArray = A;
            if(p<r)
            {
                q = (p+r)/2;
                Merge_Sort(A,p,q);
                Merge_Sort(A, q + 1, r);
                Merge(A,p,q,r);
            }
        }
        public string show()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(mArray[i].ToString() + " ");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And this is how i go about sorting:

```
        int[] arr = { 10, 12, 5, 6, 30, 1, 11, 120, 12 };
        MergeSort ms = new MergeSort(arr);
        ms.Merge_Sort(arr, 0, arr.Length );
        MessageBox.Show(ms.show());
```

But i keep getting the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` on many places in my `Merge` function. I have tried to implement the algorithm as stated in the book by CLRS(Coremen). But i keep getting this error, i have been at it since 3 days - please help.

Answer (score 1):

You've an error in line `left[i] = A[p + i - 1];` because you're passing wrong values for your parameters. Indeed, in that line, `p` is zero. In the first execution of loop, having `i=0` the resulting position in the `A` array is `-1`, that causes the IndexOutOfRange exception, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I think i am fully aware of where i am getting the error and the question is not where i am getting the error its about seeking for a solution. Its ridiculous to see this answer got 2 votes as well. Why? Because someone was able use a debugger to find a runtime error. Come one even i can do that.

Comment: @Lohit The purpose of my answer was to explain you why you have those error (where the error was, indeed, was not requested by you and I didn't care) and the reason of this, that is you need to review the algorithm, because it's wrong what you're doing, since you're passing the wrong values for your parameters. It's even ridiculous that someone asks help here and he's not even able to figure out the reason of the error and to study a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Lohit To solve your homework or to give you a working algorithm isn't my job. Here, in SO, everybody asks help for everything, and the people doesn't solve your exercise and they don't work for you. They can just give you a suggestion about what the problem is and/or how to solve it. It's up to you to learn, understand, and fix the problem.